# Definition of sum of ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I've defined the sum of ordinals inductively as:

\begin{align}\alpha+0&=\alpha \\ 
\alpha+(\beta+1)&=(\alpha+\beta)+1\\ 
\alpha+\lambda&=\sup\{\alpha+\beta\,|\,\beta<\lambda\}\quad \mbox{(if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal)} \end{align}

The question is: is it equivalent to define the sum of ordinals inductively as  $\alpha+\lambda=\sup\{\alpha+\beta\,|\,\beta<\lambda\}$ for evey ordinal $\alpha,\lambda$ even if $\lambda$ is not a limit ordinal? What goes wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This goes wrong for successors (unsurprisingly). For example, suppose that $\lambda = 1$, then
$$
\sup \{ \alpha + \beta : \beta < \lambda \} = \sup \{ \alpha + 0 \} = \alpha.
$$
In fact, it goes wrong for *every* successor ordinal. Let's say $\lambda = \gamma + 1$ for some $\gamma$, then:
$$
\sup \{ \alpha + \beta : \beta < \lambda \} = \sup \{ \alpha + \beta : \beta < \gamma + 1 \} = \sup \{ \alpha + \beta : \beta \leq \gamma \} = \alpha + \gamma.
$$

Of course, "going wrong" here is not really a precise term. An operation $\oplus$, defined inductively by $\alpha \oplus 0 = \alpha$ and $\alpha \oplus \beta = \sup \{ \alpha \oplus \gamma : \gamma < \beta \}$ for $\beta > 0$, is a perfectly fine definition. It is just not an interesting one, because the above essentially shows that $\alpha \oplus \beta = \alpha$ for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$. So "going wrong" here would mean that this operation does not really define addition as we would expect.

Comment: Why though $\sup \{ \alpha \} = \alpha$? That would imply that $\alpha\in\alpha$ which is absurd

Comment: There is a difference between $\sup \{ \alpha \}$ and $\sup \alpha$. In general $\sup X$ means that we take the least upper bound of the elements in $X$. So $\alpha$ is an upper bound of the elements in $\{ \alpha \}$, because $\alpha \leq \alpha$, and it is clearly the least upper bound. While for $\sup \alpha$ we still have that $\alpha$ is an upper bound, it is only the last upper bound if $\alpha$ is a limit. Concrete example: $\sup \{3\} = 3$ while $\sup 3 = \sup \{0, 1, 2\} = 2$.

Comment: Ok now it's crystal clear, thank you :)

Comment: Glad that helped :) Could you accept the answer? That way other users can see there is a satisfactory answer to this question.